# Creating iOS App using Java Enterprise

Tags: ios, jakarta-ee

I created a Java Enterprise Web Application.
Now i want to create a ios app for mobile devices and i want 
to communicate with enterprise java beans out of my project.

Is there any framework or something else which makes it
possible to access my java beans through an ios app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a RESTful web service which sends json or xml response from server side to iOS . Use [URL Loading Guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) or http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial for connecting to the server from iOS client. You can consider using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for the same purpose as well.